# jQuery: What does $("html") mean?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What does `$("html")` mean?

i.e. `$("html").scrollTop(0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means to select the `<html>` element in the page, and scroll to it's top position.  Since that's the **very** top of the document, you're scrolling the browser all the way up.

Answer (score 2):

`$("html")` selects all elements of the type `html`. And that’s the root element in HTML. The same can be done with <del>`$(document)` or</del> `$(document.documentElement)`.

Comment: Are you sure that $('html') == $(document)?

Comment: is this true? I didn't think the root <html> tag had all the same properties as the document object does.

Comment: @Sinan Y.: You’re right. `$(document)` refers to the document and not the root element.